Stylelint Format on Save Causing Duplicate Style Declarations in SASS File
Bit of an odd one here —
When saving an SCSS file with "format on save" turned on, stylelint will duplicate css properties that come after a double-slash comment. See screen shots below.
This only happens on "format on save." It does not happen when invoking the "Fix All" command. It happens even if there is a totally blank config file (or if no config is specified.)
If I remove the double-slash comments, the error disappears. If I disable the extension the problem goes away.



